# I can not access my storage account from sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to access my azure storage account from my sql server but the problem is that I enter the name and account key in the slq server but it shows me the following error "authentication failed for account groupadcount201712434 and the provided key, please provide a valid key and try again" I renew the key but it still shows me the error, and with other groups if...

Comment: Is there a question here...

Comment: Please include a question so that we can attempt to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it doesn't connected with account type. You just don't have an ability to interact with MS Azure from your SQL Server.

I would suggest you submit a feature request to Microsoft directly at this site https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback

This connect site will serve as a connecting point between you and Microsoft.